# ArcGIS, move map to point using ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I'm new on ArcGis (and also Angular, I start today developing in both), can't find an example on how to move the map to certain point, I was trying:

```
this.mapa.map.centerAt(new Point(-118.15, 33.80));
```

But I have a javascript error `TocComponent.html:10 ERROR ReferenceError: Point is not defined`

When I do `console.log(this.mapa.map);` I got this (I put this in case someone is wondering if `this.mapa.map` was incorrect):

[image]

EDIT: My solution, same as the answer. It not all, it's a demo of my app with Angular:

```
import { MapaComponent } from '../mapa/mapa.component';

// some code

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private arcgisService: ArcgisApiService, private mapa: MapaComponent) { }

    // another code

    onChangeSomething(evt: any): void {
        // more code
        loadModules([
            'esri/geometry/Point'
        ]).then(([Point]) => {
            const my_center = new Point([-99.94867549215655, 20.55088183550196]);
            this.mapa.map.centerAndZoom(my_center, 5);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not be including the [Point](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/point-amd.html) module in your AMD includes at the top of your file. Your list should include `esri/geometry/Point` like this:

```
require([
  "esri/map", 
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/geometry/Point",
], function(Map, FeatureLayer, Point) {

    [... the rest of your code ...]

});
```

Comment: I did it yesterday, something like you said, thanks man. My code of the solution is in the answer for better readability as an EDIT.